# Why is the object pronoun *lo* (it) used in these sentences?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, sintaxis

I was speaking to a Spanish native on Speaky and she used the following sentences

> Es loco lo sé. *It's crazy I know.*
>
> Eso lo supe en la universidad. *I knew that at University.*

This use is confusing to me because if I was translating these English sentences to Spanish I would have omitted *lo* in both cases.

Comment: the indicative "lo" and "le" are different from one another, while lo works in the direct object, le works with the indirect object

Comment: @walen - Good find, and I agree.

Comment: @walen I disagree again, the OP knows what *lo* is, they just doesn't understand why it's being used with *saber* (because in English the DO wouldn't get used).

Comment: @guifa I agree with you, this question is more basic than the previous ones, maybe the word is the same, but the reason behind the use is different, and for the usage of "lo". i would like to see similar  questions with different explanations for the community as both direct and indirect objects are complex to explain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different things are happening there. Your first example is actually not correct in Spanish as written, as it's not, I think, in English; there should be a comma in there, because there are two propositions:

> *Es loco, lo sé.* = "It's crazy, I know."

The Spanish equivalent of "(...), I know" is not the literal translation. *Lo sé* properly means "I know it", where "it" refers to the fact that you've stated just before that. You can also add *ya* and either leave the pronoun or drop it (*ya lo sé* or *ya sé* = "I already know"). You cannot under any circumstances say just *sé* "I know" in a phrase like that.

On to the second sentence:

> *Eso lo supe en la Universidad.* = "That I knew at University."

There you have a different case. Following the usual word order in Spanish (subject - verb - object) you would say *(Yo) supe eso en la Universidad.* Note there's no pronoun *lo* there. But that's not what you're saying here. You're moving the direct object (*eso*) to the front in order to make it the topic of the sentence. When that happens in a sentence like this, it's as if you have left the direct object slot empty, and since it has to be filled, we use the pronoun (in this case, *lo*). In way what you're saying is equivalent to

> *En cuanto a eso, lo supe en la Universidad.* = "As for that, I knew it at University."

Some examples of this latter kind:

- *El árbol lo talaron ayer.* = "The tree, they felled it yesterday."
- *La nueva mesa me la enviarán mañana.* = "The new table, they will send it to me tomorrow."
- *A los perros los vacunamos cuando cumplen un mes.* = "The dogs, we vaccine them when they turn one month old."
- *Tu asunto lo veré más tarde.* = "Your thing, I'll see about it later."

The pronoun is compulsory in all these cases. In English you can say things like "The table they will send tomorrow" or "Your problem I'll attend to later", but not in Spanish. Note also how in English these ideas would be more commonly conveyed using the passive voice ("The tree was felled yesterday"), which in fact achieves the same thing (turning the object into a subject and moving it to the front, which makes it the topic). The passive voice is not nearly as common in Spanish, least of all spoken Spanish.

Comment: partially because the first sentence was not correctly written in english as well, "It's crazy I know" should be written " it's crazy i know THAT/IT , creating a indication, and thus indicating we need to use the "direct indicative "lo/la"

Comment: @Erin "It's crazy, I know" is perfectly fine English.  Although "It's crazy, I know that" is grammatical English, it does not fit the context (it would work if the context were something like "It's crazy, I know *that*, but I don't know this easy thing), ditto for "It's crazy, I know it" which would virtually always be interpreted as "it's crazy [that] I know it [=some fact]" comma or not.

Comment: @guifa, then you have to translate it as "es loco, yo se" instead of "es loco, lo se", without the indicative the translation is different,  
also, it's crazy that i know it translates as "es loco que lo sepa"

Comment: @Erin One can translate words or one can translate meaning.  They don't always give the same result.  I've never heard a Spanish-speaker say "es ___, yo sé", they always say "es ___, lo sé" for what an English-speaker would express as "It's ___, I know".  For what the English-speaker means with "It's ___, I know that", the Spanish speaker would employ a demonstrative likely along with the direct object as well (depending on if it's being contrastive): "Es ____, *eso* [lo] sé".

Comment: yes @guifa, but you have to understand the reason behind the translation if you want to answer what the OP is asking,  in this case is because there's an indicative (not written) in the sentence why it should be translated that way, but as you said, using different translations actually shows the same result, the OP is asking in specific why is the "lo" there and the answer should explain it.

Comment: @pablodf76 Thank you for the excellent explanation.

Comment: @ guifa You explained the problem better than my question. :)

Comment: Pablo, may I suggest that when you're writing an answer for a beginner, that you restrict your examples to the present tense, as much as possible?  Also, that you try to choose common vocabulary items that beginners are likely to be familiar with (i.e. avoid words like *talar*).  I think this would make some of your answers even stronger. // In this case I don't see a need to explain about word order in so much detail.  (But it was very interesting to read in its own right....)

Comment: @aparente001 I'll try and do that. The explanation about word order has to do with why the pronoun must be present in the example, where it would not if the order was the more usual one.

Answer (score 0):

When "it" or "that" are used as indicatives of the subject they are replaced by Lo/La .

And interesting case is the "le"  that is used when the indication refeers to someone else.

You can research more about this with the Direct object and Indirect object, and to understand this i would recommend to read in Spanish rather to trying to translate from english.

Also for this specific case maybe "Dora" is a good example , with her signature Phrase "We did it/lo Hicimos"

Comment: My Spanish is no where near as good to start reading about Spanish grammar unfortunately. Hopefully it will be soon. :)

Comment: @Spanishbeginner - I'm not sure where you live, but many public libraries and elementary school libraries have children's books in Spanish.  If you go to browse, try to choose books that were originally written in Spanish, since some of the translated books are not the best translations in the world.

Comment: also in this specific case maybe "Dora" is a good example , with her signature Phrase "We did it/ lo Hicimos"..

Comment: @Erin - Do you want to add that to your answer?  They say comments are ephemeral....  I just realized today that you changed your username, you used to be "Mike," right?  Should I say welcome back?  I was wondering recently what had happened to you.

Comment: Yup, I'm back, i was doing experiments with my other stack exchange accounts and after switching one account it switched them all and i've been to lazy to switch my name back

Comment: @Mike - Oh, well hello again!  When I logged on today and saw that you had signed something as Mike I was afraid I had put my foot in my mouth and sort of outed you.  Sounds like you're comfortable with being known as Mike again. // It's actually quite interesting to take gender into account in the difficulties you've experienced, as described in your recent Meta question.  I personally think that the feminine name combined with your very direct SE style tended to exacerbate some of the tensions.  Many, many people expect a softer approach from women than from men, and I myself sometimes ...

Comment: ...felt disconcerted by some of your writing over the last few weeks, when I thought it was being written by a new participant named Erin.  On the other hand, maybe I'm particularly dense and most other Spanish Beta participants noticed that Erin = Mike long before I did....

Comment: @Mike - I can't find your other SE accounts.

Comment: just made them public again

Answer (score 0):

In online communication, people often omit punctuation.  The first sentence is actually

> Es loco, lo sé. *It's crazy, I know*.  OR *It's crazy; I realize that.*

For the second sentence, I'll give an alternate, freer translation that will hopefully help to convey the idea:

> Eso lo supe en la universidad. *I came to know that at University.*

You would like to know why "lo" is being included, since when you tried to go from the English idea to a Spanish sentence, you didn't include "lo."

The answer is that it is idiomatic to include "lo" in sentences such as these.

Note that object pronouns typically go *before* the verb in Spanish, for example

- Yo tengo tu libro --> Yo lo tengo.
- Yo sé que tú tienes mi libro --> Yo sé que tú lo tienes.